# How do I select and choose a value from a dropdownlist in IE using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

More details [can be seem here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEuFm.png)

Below is the code for the list.
How do I select and choose a value from a `dropdownlist` in IE using VBA?

```
<td class="form-label">


<select name="startTime" class="select"><option value="00:00">00:00</option>
<option value="00:30">00:30</option><option value="01:00">01:00</option>
<option value="01:30">01:30</option><option value="02:00">02:00</option>
<option value="02:30">02:30</option><option value="03:00">03:00</option>
<option value="03:30">03:30</option><option value="04:00">04:00</option>
<option value="04:30">04:30</option><option value="05:00">05:00</option>
<option value="05:30">05:30</option><option value="06:00">06:00</option>
<option value="06:30">06:30</option><option value="07:00">07:00</option>
<option value="07:30">07:30</option><option value="08:00" 
selected="selected">08:00</option><option value="08:30">08:30</option>
<option value="09:00">09:00</option><option value="09:30">09:30</option>
<option value="10:00">10:00</option><option value="10:30">10:30</option>
<option value="11:00">11:00</option><option value="11:30">11:30</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00</option><option value="12:30">12:30</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps:

```
Set dropOptions = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")
For Each op In dropOptions
    If op.getAttribute("name") = "startTime" Then
        op.Focus
        op.selectedIndex = <value>
    End If
Exit For
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```vb
Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.navigate your_url ' Enter the url of the page you want to navigate to here

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set Doc = IE.Document
Set OptionElements= Doc.getElementsByTagName("option")

For Each e In OptionElements
    If e.Value = "4:00" Then 'Change to whatever you want
        e.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next e
```

Comment: @mark you need to set the Document of the website first, please see the edit.